# How can I prevent lxml from auto-closing empty elements when serializing to string?

Tags: python, lxml

I am parsing a huge xml file which contains many empty elements such as

```
<MemoryEnv></MemoryEnv>
```

When serializing with

```
etree.tostring(root_element, pretty_print=True)
```

the output element is collapsed to

```
<MemoryEnv/>
```

Is there any way to prevent this? the `etree.tostring()` does not provide such a facility.

Is there a way interfere with lxml's `tostring()` serializer?

Btw, the `html` module does not work. It's not designed for XML, and
it does not create empty elements in their original form.

The problem is, that although collapsed and uncollapsed forms of an empty element are  equivalent, the
program that parses this file won't work with collapsed empty elements.

Comment: add a space between the opening and the closing tags?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to do it. Ensure that the `text` value for all empty elements is not `None`.

Example:

```
from lxml import etree

XML = """
<root>
  <MemoryEnv></MemoryEnv>
  <AlsoEmpty></AlsoEmpty>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</root>"""

doc = etree.fromstring(XML)

for elem in doc.iter():
    if elem.text == None:
        elem.text = ''

print etree.tostring(doc)
```

Output:

```xml
<root>
  <MemoryEnv></MemoryEnv>
  <AlsoEmpty></AlsoEmpty>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</root>
```

---

An alternative is to use the [`write_c14n()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write_c14n) method to write [canonical XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML) (which does not use the special empty-element syntax) to a file.

```
from lxml import etree

XML = """
<root>
  <MemoryEnv></MemoryEnv>
  <AlsoEmpty></AlsoEmpty>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</root>"""

doc = etree.fromstring(XML)

doc.getroottree().write_c14n("out.xml")
```

Comment: I did that but somehow it meshes up everything.
Also it's not very nice to iterate the whole document because of a restriction.

Anyway, I managed to use canonical XML method (c14n) for printing and it works with lxml, it does not collapse empty elements, although it does not pretty print any additions to the element tree

Comment: "Somehow it meshes up everything". What does that mean?

Comment: I tried to add empty string to elements with 'None' text property, and the result is an non-pretty-printed xml file. 

Somehow, If I iterate the tree of elements, the pretty_print brakes down.

I didn't check for validity of the result , since I need to produce output that has to be diffed... (it's a version-ed file).

I don't understand how pretty-print works for lxml, as you read, it works partially for the c14n method (strange huh?)

Comment: When you say "it works partially for the c14n method", what do you mean by "partially"? Is it still not quite what you want?

Comment: Yes, mzjn, it is, what I said is that 'c14n' prevents empty elements from collapsing but pretty_print does not  work completely when this method is chosen. Any added elements to the tree are printed inline.

Comment: I think the "How can I prevent lxml from auto-closing empty elements when serializing to string?" question has been answered. I understand that it is not what you want, but the requirements about pretty-printing and ability to do a diff are not clearly explained in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Using XML method (c14n) for printing and it works with lxml, it does not collapse empty elements.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> s = "<MemoryEnv></MemoryEnv>"
>>> root_element = etree.XML(s)
>>> etree.tostring(root_element, method="c14n")
b'<MemoryEnv></MemoryEnv>'
```