# edit xml file without fixing format using lxml etree

Tags: python, xml, lxml

While editing xml file in python using lxml it seems the etree.write() operation fixes the formatting of the file.

Code:

```
def update_file(xmlfile, xpath, data):
    parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser()
    tree = lxml.etree.parse(xmlfile, parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
    insert_at = root.xpath(xpath)[0]
    insert_data = lxml.etree.fromstring(data)
    insert_at.append(insert_data)
    tree.write(xmlfile, method='xml')
```

The code inserts given tag at xpath however, it also fixes the format of `<book id="bk102" >` to `<book id="bk102">` removing extra space before > and shortens `<price></price> to <price/>` which I don't want it to change.

Original xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <price>150</price>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102" >
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <price></price>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Updated file:

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <price>150</price>
      <newtag>hello</newtag>                <!-- expected change -->
</book>
   <book id="bk102">                        <!-- unwanted change -->
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <price/>                              <!-- unwanted change -->
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Is there a way to edit the file without fixing the format of other tags using lxml?

Comment: These are minor details that do not change the meaning of the XML. If you insist on keeping `<price></price>`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34111154/407651.

Comment: Thank you @mzjn. I understand these changes do not impact the functionality.  Any idea on how to not format the spacing (<book id="1"   > to <book id="1">) ?

Comment: No, sorry, I cannot think of a way to make lxml keep that space.