# Add an element to an xml file without changing the source data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I need to add a sub-element for each `<element>`, at the same time so that the original data does not change in any way.
Initial data:

```
<main>
  <element formatVersion="1.0">
    <firstValue>firstText</firstValue>
    <path><![CDATA[path]]></path>
    <!--Stt-->
    <code />
  </element>
  <element formatVersion="2.0">
    <firstValue>firstText_2</firstValue>
    <path><![CDATA[path]]></path>
    <code></code>
  </element>
</main>
```

If I use

```
import lxml.etree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
tree = ET.parse(xml_file, parser)
tree.write("signatures2.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, method='xml')
```

Then all tags of the type `<code></code>` change to `<code />`
If I use:

```
tree.write("signatures2.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, method='html')
```

On the contrary, all tags of the type `<code />` change to `<code></code>`

After all the changes, I need to get the following:

```
<main>
  <element formatVersion="1.0">
    <firstValue>firstText</firstValue>
    <secondValue>New_element</secondValue>
    <path><![CDATA[path]]></path>
    <!--Stt-->
    <code />
  </element>
  <element formatVersion="2.0">
    <firstValue>firstText_2</firstValue>
    <secondValue>New_element_2</secondValue>
    <path><![CDATA[path]]></path>
    <!--Stt-->
    <code></code>
  </element>
</main>
```

How do I leave the original data unchanged?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34111154/407651

Comment: @mzjn I saw this discussion and your answer there, I tried it on my own example but`method="c14n"` converts `<code />` in `<code></code>` changing the source data

Comment: You want the existing `<code />` to be unchanged. You also want the existing `<code></code>` to be unchanged. I'm not sure there is a good solution to that.

Comment: @mzjn, yes, you understood me correctly. Can you tell me if there was any way to force such lxml tags to be "ignored" so that when writing they are simply skipped without changes?

Comment: @FedorMarch - The problem you're running into is that when the XML is parsed, it's no longer serialized XML; it's just a bunch of objects. When the XML is serialized (`tree.write()`) it's serializing based on its own rules. It's not based on how the input was serialized. There is _some_ control over the serialization ([see here](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation)), but I don't think there is any configuration to do what you're asking. Also see `XMLParser` for controlling some of what happens when parsing (like CDATA handling): https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html