lxml.etree.tostring show both start and end tags for empty node
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.XML('<foo class="abc"></foo>')
print(etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8'))

The above code shows the following.
<foo class="abc"/>

How can I make it not to contract the result, but show <foo class="abc"></foo> instead?

Here's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34177354/2834978

Use the option method='html'.
